# IntelliJ community Perforce plug-in

Tags: open-source, intellij-idea, perforce

I used to love using [IntelliJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) but my new company doesn't spend money on [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s. Now with the release of IntelliJ Community Edition, the only obstacle I have is that my company uses [Perforce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforce).   Does anyone know if there are Perforce plug-ins that work with the Community Edition?

Comment: They won't pay for an IDE, but they will pay for a source control system that is more expensive per user than the IDE???

Comment: @Yishai - it's a little more complicated than that.  I love IntelliJ, but my dev group (one of several) is cheap and wouldn't try it EVEN THOUGH my company supports the developers quite generously (full MSDN subscriptions for the .net guys and Perforce licenses for everyone, I think that's over $4k per developer just for basic tools).  So yes, we use Perforce for source control but stick to Eclipse (most of us in my little dev group) because it's free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obsolete VCS-based Perfoce plugin does not work at all.

The obsolete non-VCS-based PerforceDirectPlugin (http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=69) works partially with the Community Edition. Several operations don't work, presumably because the plugin API has changed. However, the basic Edit/Add/Revert/Sync operations work.

Integrating it into the Community Edition is another story. I'm used to "edit on type" so I habitually type return when the warning dialog comes up that the file I'm trying to edit is read-only. This is bad, because later it's difficult to find files I have accidentally edited using the file system, and check them out for edit in Perforce.

The other big missing piece is the VCS change bar on the left, which is very useful for seeing where you've changed a file and quickly going back to read/edit those changes.

Answer (score 0):

The community edition is announced, not released, so it is a drop too early for that. There was a separate plug-in in older versions of IDEA, and I imagine when the community edition gets released and gets going, someone will write one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Simple P4 Plugin. It only has the basic functionalities. I tried it it is pretty good.  http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7420?pr=idea_ce